# how to Include source code inside the mvn built jar

Tags: maven

We are changing our projects from ant to mvn build.
In the ant build jar - xyz.jar [we used to have the source files inside]
xyz.sources.jar inside xyz.jar

How can I do the same through pom.xml. I tried maven-source-plugin, but this creates the sources jar inside target folder. I want this sources jar inside output jar.

Thanks.

Comment: First why do you package the source into the same artifact as the executable code? It does not belong there. In Maven you create a separate artifact for example via maven-source-plugin into xyz-1.0-source.jar ...and try to follow the conventions this will make life easier...

Answer (score 1):

The convention is to ship these artifacts separately. Offering them separately in a Maven repository allows tools like Eclipse and IntelliJ to match the sources to the binaries automatically, and life is good.

To do what you want to do, you could run the [Maven Source Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/index.html) before the main JAR file is packaged (e.g. in the `prepare-package` phase), and have it write the sources JAR to the `target/classes/` folder, and not attach. Like so:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>source-jar</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                <finalName>filename-of-generated-jar-file</finalName>
                <attach>false</attach>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Remove outputDirectory from the configuration cause it's the default. Furthermore remove finalName cause maven-source-plugin does not have such configuration...

Comment: Respect to long-time Maven contributors like yourself, but I respectfully disagree: default [`outputDirectory`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-mojo.html#outputDirectory) is `${project.build.directory}`. The `finalName` suggested [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/examples/configureplugin.html); while it doesn't appear in the goal's documentation, it works. It's defined in [AbstractSourceJarMojo](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/blob/trunk/maven-source-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/source/AbstractSourceJarMojo.java#L168).

Comment: First related to `outputDirectory` you are right. I've mistaken that. And yes the default is as you stated `${project.build.directory}`. I would suggest to use the goal `jar-no-fork` instead of `jar`. The `finalName` should not working cause it's marked as `readonly=true` (but it does). This means the parameter should be available via goals and so it needs to be [fixed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSOURCES-108) seemed to be an issue...thanks for finding this...

Comment: So can we have the source code of other dependent jars attached as well?       I tried maven-assembly-plugin     <configuration>
<outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
<descriptorRefs>
<descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
</descriptorRefs>
</configuration>             but xyz.dependency.jar is inside xyz.jar which itself is inside another xyz.jar

Comment: Yes, my answer is still valid.

Comment: @SanderVerhagen Please let me know how to configure the pom for this. Now I have xyz.sources.jar inside xyz.jar. How can I have the abc.sources.jar inside xyz.jar

Comment: Add the snippet from my answer to the POM file. If that's not clear, please be more specific about what your remaining question is.